# Is there a way in Angular to get a mat-slider with a width less than 128px?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-slider

I haven't been able to find any ways to get a mat-slider smaller than 128px wide. Is there a way to do this? I have used transform: scale(); as a temporary solution, but this creates issues with other elements. An example of the type of slider with which I am working can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pmvaaebvxvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslider-overview-example.css). The css width can be increased, but once you lower it to 128px, it can't get any smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.mat-slider-horizontal` has a `min-width` property of `128px`.

You can override this with:

```
.mat-slider-horizontal {
  min-width: unset;
}
```

Be aware that the min-width was probably there for good reason and this may introduce other issues.

Here's the updated Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5leng?file=src/app/slider-overview-example.css